# "Unknown column 'ID' in 'where clause'" при выполнении SELECT запроса

Tags: mysql

Вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT  `UserID` AS  `ID`
FROM  `Users` WHERE `ID` = 'FREE'
```

Comment: работать с столбиком по алиасу можно только на уровень выше (в отличии от алиаса таблички):

    select * from (SELECT userId AS id, u.* FROM Users u) where userId = 'FREE'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT UserID AS ID FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'FREE'
```

Comment: Так мне нужно чтобы WHERE ID = 'FREE' было, так как я хочу несколько раз обращаться к одной талице

Comment: Нельзя в условии использовать алиас (псевдоним) - только имена колонок в таблице. В вашем случае, ID это всевдоним, надо использовать UserID.

Comment: @Rams666, то есть вы утверждаете что мой запрос неправильный?

Comment: Нет, ваш запрос как раз правильный - мой комментарий адресован автору вопроса.